# Derived Class cannot access Parent class method

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am getting an error "class Derived has no member named 'getX'" When I try to compile code like this:

```
class Base
{
    public:
        int getX() {return x};
    protected:
        int x;

};   

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
        void myFunction(){int y = getX()};

};
```

I contrived this example to help clarify, because I got a lot of errors like this when my derived class tries to use methods from the parent class that it should have inherited. I have tried using the 'this' keyword before the method invocation, but that did not work either. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please show the complete code. Also mention what errors you got.

Comment: You have couple of misplaced `;`s in your posted code. Other than that, it looks OK to me.

Comment: Remember that you need to start with fixing the first error. If there's a problem with the base class, it doesn't exist for the compiler. (And don't post code that doesn't cause the error you're wondering about.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correcting your code

```
class Base
{
    public:
        int getX() {return x; }
    protected:
        int x;

};   

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
        int myFunction(){int y = getX(); return y; }

};
```

compiles for me with

```
g++ -c -o /dev/null -Wall derive.c
```

.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly read the errors.Here there is no issue in calling base class function. The compilation errors are related to syntax mistake.

Refer the compiling code in below.

```
class Base
{
 protected:
     int x;

 public:
     int getX() {return x;};
};

class Derived : public Base
{
  public:
      void myFunction(){int y = getX();};

};
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use better coding style, that may solve an issue.

Your code:

```
int getX() {return x};
```

It actually is:

```
int getX() 
{
    return x
};
```

As you see `;` is put in wrong place. And have to be:

```
int getX() 
{
    return x;
}
```

The same problem is in `void myFunction(){int y = getX()};` line.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trying to get the code to compile, I just gave up and copied all of the parent's methods and members into the children classes. Thanks for the answers anyways.